# How can I use axios or any other http request client package in my Adonisjs Controller

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

I want to call to a external API to get some data while I'm inside the controller.

Let's say, There is two different project, one is hosted in `example.com` and the other one is in `a.example.com`. 
Now, when I am on `a.example.com sub-domain`, I want the user data who has logged in `example.com` in that sub-domain.

For testing purpose, I set an API url for the in `example.com` which will return the expected json data.

My Problem is, I want to call axios to that API from the `a.example.com` domain. But I can not require the axios package inside my controller.

Here is my controller of `a.example.com`:

```
'use strict'


const axios = require('axios')
class UserController {


    async getAllUser({ request, auth, response, axios }) {

        await axios('http://a.example.com/getUser')
            .then(response => {
                return response;
            });


    }

}

export default UserController
```

But I get this error :

`'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module' export default UserController`

I don't know how to solve this, can anyone help me fix this?

Answer (score 0):

In Adonis, you use "use" instead of require.

```
const Axios = use('Axios');
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
export default UserController
```

Use

```
module.exports = UserController
```